# Reading specific XML elements from XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML file

```
<lexicon>
<word>
  <base>a</base>
  <category>determiner</category>
  <id>E0006419</id>
</word>
<word>
  <base>abandon</base>
  <category>verb</category>
  <id>E0006429</id>
  <ditransitive/>
  <transitive/>
</word>
<word>
  <base>abbey</base>
  <category>noun</category>
  <id>E0203496</id>
</word>
<word>
  <base>ability</base>
  <category>noun</category>
  <id>E0006490</id>
</word>
<word>
  <base>able</base>
  <category>adjective</category>
  <id>E0006510</id>
  <predicative/>
  <qualitative/>
</word>
<word>
  <base>abnormal</base>
  <category>adjective</category>
  <id>E0006517</id>
  <predicative/>
  <qualitative/>
</word>
<word>
  <base>abolish</base>
  <category>verb</category>
  <id>E0006524</id>
  <transitive/>
</word>
</lexicon>
```

I need to read this file with C# application, and if only the `category` is `verb` I want to print its entire element `word`.
How can I do that?

Comment: have u tried using Linq to XML ?

Comment: Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: @Ruba you are supposed to do your own research first then come when you are having trouble.  A google search or a search of SO would have shown you how do parse an XML.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use linq to xml.

```
    var xmlStr = File.ReadAllText("fileName.xml");


    var str = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);

    var result = str.Elements("word").
Where(x => x.Element("category").Value.Equals("verb")).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: NB: the XElement class is in the System.Xml.Linq namespace

Answer (score 7):

You could use an [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp), too. A bit old fashioned but still effective:

```
using System.Xml;

...

XmlDocument xmlDocument;

xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);

foreach (XmlElement xmlElement in 
    xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("word[category='verb']"))
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(xmlElement.OuterXml);
}
```

Comment: I disagree that XPath is old fashioned, I like XPath a lot

Comment: I mean.. you can like it all you want, but compared to linq to xml it is old fashioned.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Can you do: `xDoc.XPathSelectElement("/root/child/element")` with `linq-to-xml` in a single row? without using `Descendants` because that looks everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I would do it (the code below has been tested, full source provided below), begin by creating a class with common properties

```
    class Word
    {
        public string Base { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
```

load using XDocument with INPUT_DATA for demonstration purposes and find element name with **lexicon** . . .

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(INPUT_DATA);
    XElement lex = doc.Element("lexicon");
```

make sure there is a value and use linq to extract the word elements from it . . .

```
    Word[] catWords = null;
    if (lex != null)
    {
        IEnumerable<XElement> words = lex.Elements("word");
        catWords = (from itm in words
                    where itm.Element("category") != null
                        && itm.Element("category").Value == "verb"
                        && itm.Element("id") != null
                        && itm.Element("base") != null
                    select new Word() 
                    {
                        Base = itm.Element("base").Value,
                        Category = itm.Element("category").Value,
                        Id = itm.Element("id").Value,
                    }).ToArray<Word>();
    }
```

The `where` statement checks if the category element exists and that the category value is not null and then check it again that it is a verb.  Then check that the other nodes also exists . . .

The linq query will return an IEnumerable< Typename > object, so we can call ToArray< Typename >() to cast the entire collection into the type we want.

Then print it to get . . .

```
[Found]
 Id: E0006429
 Base: abandon
 Category: verb

[Found]
 Id: E0006524
 Base: abolish
 Category: verb
```

**Full Source**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {

        class Word
        {
            public string Base { get; set; }
            public string Category { get; set; }
            public string Id { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(INPUT_DATA);
            XElement lex = doc.Element("lexicon");
            Word[] catWords = null;
            if (lex != null)
            {
                IEnumerable<XElement> words = lex.Elements("word");
                catWords = (from itm in words
                            where itm.Element("category") != null
                                && itm.Element("category").Value == "verb"
                                && itm.Element("id") != null
                                && itm.Element("base") != null
                            select new Word() 
                            {
                                Base = itm.Element("base").Value,
                                Category = itm.Element("category").Value,
                                Id = itm.Element("id").Value,
                            }).ToArray<Word>();
            }

            //print it
            if (catWords != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Words with <category> and value verb:\n");
                foreach (Word itm in catWords)
                    Console.WriteLine("[Found]\n Id: {0}\n Base: {1}\n Category: {2}\n", 
                        itm.Id, itm.Base, itm.Category);
            }
        }

        const string INPUT_DATA =
        @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
        <lexicon>
        <word>
          <base>a</base>
          <category>determiner</category>
          <id>E0006419</id>
        </word>
        <word>
          <base>abandon</base>
          <category>verb</category>
          <id>E0006429</id>
          <ditransitive/>
          <transitive/>
        </word>
        <word>
          <base>abbey</base>
          <category>noun</category>
          <id>E0203496</id>
        </word>
        <word>
          <base>ability</base>
          <category>noun</category>
          <id>E0006490</id>
        </word>
        <word>
          <base>able</base>
          <category>adjective</category>
          <id>E0006510</id>
          <predicative/>
          <qualitative/>
        </word>
        <word>
          <base>abnormal</base>
          <category>adjective</category>
          <id>E0006517</id>
          <predicative/>
          <qualitative/>
        </word>
        <word>
          <base>abolish</base>
          <category>verb</category>
          <id>E0006524</id>
          <transitive/>
        </word>
        </lexicon>";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var word = xdoc.Elements("word")
               .SingleOrDefault(w => (string)w.Element("category") == "verb");
```

[This query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549274.aspx) will return whole word `XElement`. If there is more than one word element with category `verb`, than you will get an `InvalidOperationException`. If there is no elements with category `verb`, result will be `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) query via [`XPathSelectElements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176.aspx) method:

```
var document = XDocument.Parse(yourXmlAsString);
var words = document.XPathSelectElements("//word[./category[text() = 'verb']]");
```